# git commit -a -m doesn't add unstaged files

Tags: git

Under what circumstances (other than a .gitignore) is a `git commit -a` not going to actually automatically `git add` unstaged files? I usually use this to save a step, but recently in one of my repos, i must explicitly `git add` the files before I commit or they are not included. There is no `.gitignore` file that would prevent automatically adding them. Is there any problem with the fact that the files are chmod a+x? Not sure that would make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git commit -a` never adds untracked files. It adds modified files and deleted files.

From `git help commit`:

```
-a, --all
    Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
    modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are
    not affected.
```

Files ignored via `.gitignore` are not included, and neither are files ignored via `.git/info/exclude`. Files in either of these cases must be explicitly added with `git add -f`.

Comment: Note that files ignored via the ignore mechanism are only ignored-when-untracked.  If a file that would be ignored, is already in the repo or is forcibly added (`git add -f`), it becomes un-ignored.  (I know part of this is in the above answer already, just attempting to be complete here. :-) )